# How to sync multiple horizontal scrollviews with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

There are horizontal scrollviewA and horizontal scrollviewB in Vstack. In addition, scrollviewB is inside a vertical scrollviewC. How can I make scrollviewB scroll horizontally in sync with scrollviewA when scrollviewA is scrolled horizontally?

I wrote following codes. I'm not sure how to sync scroll ScrollViewA and ScrollViewB.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CssOm.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let grids = Array(repeating: GridItem(.fixed(100), spacing: 10, alignment: .leading), count: 10)
    let gridsHeader = Array(repeating: GridItem(.fixed(100), spacing: 10, alignment: .leading), count: 1)

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                HStack {
                    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        LazyHGrid(rows: gridsHeader, spacing: 30) {
                            ForEach(photoArray0) { item in
                                ForEach(0..<1) { num in
                                    Image(item.imageName)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(8)
                                }
                            }
                        }.padding()
                    }
                    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        LazyHGrid(rows: gridsHeader, spacing: 30) {
                            ForEach(photoArray) { item in
                                ForEach(0..<1) { num in
                                    Image(item.imageName)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(8)
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }.padding()
                    }
                }
            }
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                HStack {
                    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        LazyHGrid(rows: grids, spacing: 30) {
                            ForEach(photoArray0) { item in
                                ForEach(0..<10) { num in
                                    Image(item.imageName)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(8)
                                }
                            }
                        }.padding()
                    }
                    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        LazyHGrid(rows: grids, spacing: 30) {
                            ForEach(photoArray) { item in
                                ForEach(0..<10) { num in
                                    Image(item.imageName)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(8)
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }.padding()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PhotoData: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var imageName:String
    var title:String
}

var photoArray = [
    PhotoData(imageName: "A", title: "a"),
    PhotoData(imageName: "B", title: "b"),
    PhotoData(imageName: "C", title: "c"),
    PhotoData(imageName: "D", title: "d"),
    PhotoData(imageName: "E", title: "e"),
    PhotoData(imageName: "F", title: "f"),
    PhotoData(imageName: "G", title: "g"),
    PhotoData(imageName: "A", title: "a"),
    PhotoData(imageName: "B", title: "b"),
    PhotoData(imageName: "C", title: "c"),
    PhotoData(imageName: "D", title: "d"),
    PhotoData(imageName: "E", title: "e"),
    PhotoData(imageName: "F", title: "f"),
    PhotoData(imageName: "G", title: "g"),
]

var photoArray0 = [
    PhotoData(imageName: "A", title: "a"),
]

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use`LazyVGrid` or `LazyHGrid` or `Grid`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
In a nutshell, I want to create a table with a fixed first column and first row, like in Excel. Am I able to create it with LazyVGrid or LazyHGrid or Grid? If so, please tell me how to create it.